# Bind text to label angular 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, label, ionic3

I am infant in angular. I want to update my label text. This is how I tried.

My html:
    `<Label class="ad-label"  text="{{ labelText }}" textWrap="true"></Label>`

My ts :
    `labelText: any='Month';`
I encounter the error

> Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'text' since it isn't a known property of 'Label'.

When I use `<a class="ad-label"  text="{{ labelText }}" textWrap="true"></a>` instead of Label text is updated using `labelText: any='Month';` How to update text of label?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `text` property(`Input` binding) is not available inside `Label` component, you can't use it. Angular is complaining about the same. Actually you should put `label` text inside the `Label` element.

```
<Label class="ad-label" textWrap="true">
   {{labelText}}
</Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means that no `text` attribute exists on the `Label` tag.

That's like using the view box attribute from SVG (`<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"></svg>`) on a idv : it doesn't exist.

I don't know what a `Label` is, so I assume it's part of a framework or library. Either try this

```
<Label class="ad-label" textWrap="true">{{ labelText }}</Label>
```

Or look at the documentation of your framework / library to see how to add the text to your label.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to bind an attribute to a variable from your .ts file you need to use [square] brackets. Like so:

```
<Label [text]="labelText"></Label>
```

Additionally, it's complaining that 'text' is not a property on the Label element. Do you mean to use ion-label?

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
labelText: any='Month'; change to labelText='Month'; in your ts file
```

or you  can use ngModel to two way binding

```
<Label class="ad-label"  [(ngModel)]="labelText" textWrap="true"></Label>
```